# The return type of jwkSelector.select(jwkSet) is List, so how does it get cast to JWKSource<SecurityContext>?

Tags: thymeleaf

I was learning about security and JWTs, and I had this curiosity. How is casting from List to a custom function done?

```
  @Bean
  public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource(RSAKey rsaKey) {
    JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
    return (jwkSelector, context) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
  }
```